# create multiple cross tables with one-line code function with gtsummary

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, gtsummary, gt

i'm having the following problem:

**Context:**
I'm using `gtsummary` to explore frequencies in a dataframe using cross variables.

**Here's my desire output:**
[image: desire table]

So that i have a main variable `tobgp` and its cross by multiple variables like `agegp` and `algp`

Attempt:
this is what i've done so far. Using the `esoph` data from the package The R Datasets Package (datasets).

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, gt, gtsummary)

multiple_table<-function(data, var){

t0<- data %>% 
  select({{var}}) %>% 
  gtsummary::tbl_summary(statistic = all_categorical()~ "{p}% ({n})",
                         digits = list(everything() ~ c(2, 0))) %>%
  modify_header(label ~ "") %>% 
  bold_labels()

#agep
t1<-data %>% 
  select({{var}}, agegp) %>% 
  gtsummary::tbl_summary(by = agegp, statistic = all_categorical()~ "{p}% ({n})",
                         digits = list(everything() ~ c(2, 0)))


#alcgp
t2<-data %>% 
  select({{var}}, alcgp) %>% 
  gtsummary::tbl_summary(by = alcgp, statistic = all_categorical()~ "{p}% ({n})",
                         digits = list(everything() ~ c(2, 0)))

#MERGE
tbl_merge(tbls = list(t0,t1,t2),
          tab_spanner = c("**Total**", "**agegp**", "**algp**")) %>%
  as_gt() %>% 
  gt::tab_source_note(gt::md("*Fuente: Empresa1*"))

}

esoph %>% 
  multiple_table(tobgp)
```

The problem with my code so far is that is specific for the crosses, to add more cross variables i have to modify the function i created which is not so friendly.

**Request:**
Create a function so that you can create the desire output with one line of code. Like this for example:

```
multiple_table(data, main, by)    

esoph %>%
    multiple_table(main=tobgp, by=c(agegp, algp)
```

So that if i want to use other variables to cross by i only have to change the `by=c()` argument.
In order to be easy to do something like:

```
esoph %>%
    multiple_table(main=tobgp, by=c(agegp, algp, variable1, variable2)
```

**Notes:**

- I've tried other functions inside `gtsummary` like `tbl_strata` which can use two variables as crosses, but doesn't suit my needs because it mixes the two cross variables like this:
  [image: the table i don't want]

This is not what i'm looking for. As you can see, Grade divides the percentage of Drug test by each Grade. This example is taken from gtsummary vignette: https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tbl_strata.html

- I think the solution for my problem could involve some workaround with `purrr`, or `apply`, i've tried some but i'm not very good using lists and iterations.

That's it. Thanks very much for listening and i hope i've been very clear. If not, feel free to ask.

**Answers 28/03/22**

Since i posted my question i've recieve to different approach answers which both work perfectly. Feel free to use the one that suits you. Thanks Mike for the answer in StackOverflow and thanks Tan, June C, Tyler Grant Smith for the answer in the Slack R4DS Community. In my case i would stick with the **approach 3**.

**Approach 1: The Mike approach**

```
library(gtsummary)
library(dplyr)
esoph <- mutate(esoph,
                ncases = ifelse(ncases > 2, "High","Low"))

multiple_table<-function(data, var, vars){

  t0 <- data %>%
    select( var  ) %>%
    gtsummary::tbl_summary(statistic = all_categorical()~ "{p}% ({n})",
                           digits = list(everything() ~ c(2, 0))) %>%
    modify_header(label ~ "") %>%
    bold_labels()


  tlist <-  lapply(vars,function(y){
    data %>%
      select( var  ,  y  ) %>%
      gtsummary::tbl_summary(by =  y  , statistic = all_categorical()~ "{p}% ({n})",
                             digits = list(everything() ~ c(2, 0)))
  })

  tabspannername <- c("**Total**", paste0("**",vars,"**"))

  tlist2 <- append(list(t0), tlist,1)


  tbl_merge(tbls = tlist2
            ,tab_spanner = tabspannername
  ) %>%
    as_gt() %>%
    gt::tab_source_note(gt::md("*Fuente: Empresa1*"))
}

multiple_table(data = esoph, var = "tobgp", vars = c("agegp", "alcgp","ncases"))
```

**Approach 2: The Tan approach**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)
library(gtsummary)

esoph

fn_subtable <- function(data, main, sub){
  data %>%
    dplyr::select({{main}},{{sub}}) %>%
    gtsummary::tbl_summary(
      by = {{sub}},
      statistic = gtsummary::all_categorical()~ "{p}% ({n})",
      digits = list(dplyr::everything() ~ c(2, 0)))

}

fn_table <-function(data, main_var, sub_vars){

  t0 <- data %>%
    dplyr::select({{main_var}}) %>%
    gtsummary::tbl_summary(statistic = gtsummary::all_categorical() ~ "{p}% ({n})",
                           digits = list(dplyr::everything() ~ c(2, 0))) %>%
    gtsummary::modify_header(label ~ "") %>%
    gtsummary::bold_labels()

  sub_tables <- purrr::map(sub_vars, ~fn_subtable(data = data, main = main_var, sub = .x))

  #MERGE
  tbls <- c(list(t0), sub_tables) %>%
    gtsummary::tbl_merge(tab_spanner = c("**Total**", paste0("**",sub_vars,"**"))) %>%
    gtsummary::as_gt() %>%
    gt::tab_source_note(gt::md("*Fuente: Empresa1*"))

  tbls

}

esoph %>% fn_table("tobgp", c("agegp", "alcgp"))
```

**Approach 3: The June C - Tyler Grant Smith approach**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)
library(gtsummary)

fn_subtable <- function(data, main, sub){
  data %>% 
    dplyr::select({{main}},{{sub}}) %>% 
    gtsummary::tbl_summary(
      by = {{sub}}, 
      statistic = gtsummary::all_categorical()~ "{p}% ({n})",
      digits = list(dplyr::everything() ~ c(2, 0)))
  
}

fn_table3 <- function(data, main_var, sub_vars){
  
  main_var <- rlang::enexpr(main_var)
  sub_vars_expr <- rlang::enexpr(sub_vars)         # 1. Capture `list(...)` call as expression
  sub_vars_args <- rlang::call_args(sub_vars_expr) # 2. Pull out the arguments (they're now also exprs)
  sub_vars_fn   <- rlang::call_fn(sub_vars_expr)   # 3. Pull out the fn call
  # 4. Evaluate the fn with expr-ed arguments (this becomes `list( expr(agegp), expr(alcgp) )` )
  sub_vars_reconstructed <- rlang::exec(sub_vars_fn, !!!sub_vars_args)
  
  # --- sub_vars replaced with sub_vars_reconstructed from here onwards ---
  
  t0 <- data %>% 
    dplyr::select({{main_var}}) %>% 
    gtsummary::tbl_summary(statistic = gtsummary::all_categorical() ~ "{p}% ({n})",
                           digits = list(dplyr::everything() ~ c(2, 0))) %>%
    gtsummary::modify_header(label ~ "") %>% 
    gtsummary::bold_labels()
  
  sub_tables <- purrr::map(sub_vars_reconstructed, ~fn_subtable(data = data, main = main_var, sub = .x))
  
  tbls <-  c(list(t0), sub_tables) %>% 
    gtsummary::tbl_merge(tab_spanner = c("**Total**", paste0("**",sub_vars_reconstructed,"**"))) %>%
    gtsummary::as_gt() %>% 
    gt::tab_source_note(gt::md("*Fuente: Empresa1*"))
  
  tbls
  
}

fn_table3(esoph,tobgp,list(agegp,alcgp))
```

Thanks very much and i hope this could be implemented as a function inside the gtsummary package because is very useful to explore frequencies with different cross variables.

Comment: its r studio 4.1.2 and gtsummary 1.5.2

Comment: so you want a wrapper function, called `multiple_table()`, where it takes a row variable and x amount of column variables correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are pretty close and only needed a few modifications. the major change is adding in an `lapply()` to loop through the `vars` input to create a list of `tbl_summary` objects. Then I create the tab spanner names from the inputs of `vars` and append the `t0` table to the list created by the `lapply()`. then you can pass `tlist2` to `tbl_merge()` with the names created with `tabspannername` to dynamically label the tables.

```
library(gtsummary)
library(dplyr)
esoph <- mutate(esoph,
                ncases = ifelse(ncases > 2, "High","Low"))

multiple_table<-function(data, var, vars){

  t0 <- data %>% 
    select( var  ) %>% 
    gtsummary::tbl_summary(statistic = all_categorical()~ "{p}% ({n})",
                           digits = list(everything() ~ c(2, 0))) %>%
    modify_header(label ~ "") %>% 
    bold_labels()
  
  
  tlist <-  lapply(vars,function(y){
    esoph %>% 
      select( var  ,  y  ) %>% 
      gtsummary::tbl_summary(by =  y  , statistic = all_categorical()~ "{p}% ({n})",
                             digits = list(everything() ~ c(2, 0)))
  })
  
 tabspannername <- c("**Total**", paste0("**",vars,"**"))
  
 tlist2 <- append(list(t0), tlist,1)
 
 
 tbl_merge(tbls = tlist2
            ,tab_spanner = tabspannername
           ) %>%
   as_gt() %>% 
   gt::tab_source_note(gt::md("*Fuente: Empresa1*"))
}


x <-  multiple_table(data = esoph, var = "tobgp", vars = c("agegp", "alcgp","ncases"))
```

Comment: Thanks Mike for the quick response and it has worked. I can see that for some reason tidyeval or lazyeval is not allowing to call the variables like tidyselect for example: multiple_table(data = esoph, var = tobgp, vars = c(agegp, alcgp, ncases)) so if you know how to solve this problem let me know. One final comment, in tlist you were calling esoph directly so it was not working for other data, i've fix this and putting the updated code in the question. Thanks very much Mike.

Comment: the way I coded it allows the user to use standard evaluation, if you want to use non-standard evaluation (NSE) (meaning unquoted variables) you will have to use the `{{` notation which you had. it just gets a bit tricky with the tab_spanner names.